# Python Removing objects from a list based on another rlist

Tags: python

I have a queryresult data

```
 data = Phone_Numbers.objects.filter(phone_no__startswith=phone_prefix)
```

I have a model

```
class Phone_Numbers(models.Model):
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    phone_no_type = models.CharField(max_length = 30,default = 'Mobile')
    phone_no_category = models.CharField(max_length = 30,default = 'Standard')  
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.phone_no== other.phone_no:
            return True
        else :
            return False
```

i have a list with phonenumber objects with only few parameters specified.
how can i filter  the list if an object having same phonenumber is alreday in queryresult data

```
data=[{phone_no:'9882822',phone_type:'landline,phone_category:'Standard'},  {phone_no:'9882821',phone_type:'landline,phone_category:'Standard'}]

insert_list=[{phone_no:'9882822'},{phone_no:'9882821'},{phone_no:'9882825'},]
```

My Expected Output is insert_list=[{phone_no:'9882825'}]

i got the result via the following way is there any better way to do it

```
 newlist=insert_list[:]
    for entry in data:
                for listentry in newlist:
                    if entry==listentry:
                        insert_list.remove(entry)
```

Comment: please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your indentation is messed up a bit. Please keep in mind that [SO](https://stackoverflow.com) is not a code writing service. This also has nothing to do with your Phone Number Objects but with handling lists.

Comment: @R4PH43L  i know So is not code writting service.i am stuck with handling python lists thats why i posted it. i know the way to do it in usual java or C# way which i added now

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your exact question but if you want to filter a list in python you have at least two possible ways to do so. First one is to use [filters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) that is my suggestion number one.

```
my_list = [{'attr': 'test'}, {'attr': 'test1'}, {'attr': 'test2'}, {'attr': 'test2'}]
my_list = filter(lambda x: x.attr is not 'test2', my_list)
```

This can be "expanded" to

```
def my_filter(element):
    return element.attr is not 'test2'

my_list = [{'attr': 'test'}, {'attr': 'test1'}, {'attr': 'test2'}, {'attr': 'test2'}]

my_list = filter(my_filter, my_list)
```

However there is a difference between [python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) and [python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) versions of filter. Python 3 filter function returns an iterator from those elements of iterable for which function returns true. In this case python 2 returns a list containing elements that filter function returns true with.

Second opportunity is to use [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), for example like this

```
list_of_objects = [x for x in list_of_objects if x.attr is not value_to_filter]
```

Here is a couple of pretty useful [examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/05/python-filter-and-list/) about this.

In your case just use something like

```
list1=[{'phone_no':928828292},{'phone_no':928828293},{'phone_no':928828294}] 
list2=[{'phone_no':928828293,type:'landline'}]

def my_filter(element):
    global list2
    for element2 in list2:
        if element['phone_no'] == element2['phone_no']:
            return False
    return True

print(filter(my_filter, list1))
```

If another list can't be global use python functools

```
from functools import partial

list1=[{'phone_no':928828292},{'phone_no':928828293},{'phone_no':928828294}] 
list2=[{'phone_no':928828293,'type':'landline'}]

def my_filter(other_list, element):
    for element2 in other_list:
        if element['phone_no'] == element2['phone_no']:
            return False
    return True

print(filter(partial(my_filter, list2), list1))
```

Comment: list1=[{phone_no:928828292},{phone_no:928828293},{phone_no:928828294}]   list2=[{phone_no:928828293,type:'landline'}]    i need to remove list2 items from list1 based even if it has other attributes

Comment: list 2 cant be global then what can we do

Comment: Here you go.. This goes totally off the topic but hope this helps you out of the trap :)